# Customizing URL pattern in existing Spring filter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-filter

I am using a third party library in a Spring-boot app which includes the following filter for all API URL's.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registerCarFilter(@Value("${car.filter.order:400}") int order) {
    final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setFilter(new CarFilter());
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    registrationBean.setOrder(order);
    return registrationBean;
}
```

Would it be possible to exclude this filter for specific URL's? and what will be the best practice to do that.

What If I don't want to execute it for "/car-status" URL?

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but maybe your Car filter should extend OncePerRequestFilter. Here is a sample

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7426

In your case shouldNotFilter may look like:

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    return "/car-status".equals(request.getServletPath());
}
```

Or request.getRequestURI() depending on your config.

Comment: But registerCarFilter method and Car Filter is the part of library, I had no control to change it. That is what the question is about. How to override the FilterRegistrationBean settings in my own code.

Comment: It allows you to extend it ?